# Adding multiple expressions to single searchmatch in splunk query

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-eks, splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to add two different expressions in the searchmatch in below query using timechart but its giving me error. Can any one help me out with the same

Its like the count2 should increase if either of expression i.e. Expr2 or Expr3 is seen.

count1 is coming correct and count2 is giving issue as incorrect

```
index="abc" sourcetype="kube:container:abc_app" source="/var/log/containers/abc-env-*" 
| timechart count(eval(searchmatch("Expr1"))) as "count1", count(eval(searchmatch("Expr2" OR "Expr3"))) as "count2"
```

Comment: @RichG can u pls guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `searchmatch` function takes a single string (possibly containing a pattern) as its argument, not a boolean expression.  Try using two `searchmatch` calls.

```
index="abc" sourcetype="kube:container:abc_app" source="/var/log/containers/abc-env-*" 
| timechart count(eval(searchmatch("Expr1"))) as "count1", count(eval(searchmatch("Expr2") OR searchmatch("Expr3"))) as "count2"
```

Comment: I think i tried it similar way also. It didnt work but lemme double check!

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a single aggregating function in a [`timechart`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/timechart#Required_arguments) call

You're trying to do *two* `count` functions

`timechart` will only do one

Comment: `timechart` support multiple aggregate function. I tried, it worked.

Comment: @KevinBui - what did you try that worked? Because the docs say it won't (and I've never seen it "work")

Comment: It's undocumented feature. I try `| timechart span=10m count, sum(elapse) , avg(elapse)` it worked.